# Sort an arrray of objects by the sum of the objects properties

Tags: javascript

My array looks like this

```
[
  {
    ...
    "code": "X",
    "pricings": [
       {
          "price": 51,
          ...
       },
       {
          "price": 51,
          ...
       }
     ]
   },
   {
     ...
     "code": "Y",
     "pricings": [
       {
         "price": 88,
         ...
       },
       {
         "price": 88,
         ...
       }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

I need to sort it by the sum of the `price` attribute (descending). So in this example the product with the code 'Y' should be on the first position.

I currently do this

```
arr.sort((a, b) => b.pricings.map(el => el.price).reduce((prev, curr) => { return prev + curr }) - a.pricings.map(el => el.price).reduce((prev, curr) => { return prev + curr }))
```

but I'm not quite sure if this is a good way to do this and i'm curious about if there is a simpler/better solution to achive the result. Maybe you could share some experience :)

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com is a good site for this kind of thing :)

Comment: Thanks @SpaceCowboy, I'll give it a try for the next question of this kind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get an array with the sums of the items and sort an array of indices with the sums at same index and map a new array in the wanted order.

The advantage of this approach is a single looping through `pricing` for each object.

```js
var array = [{ code: "X", pricings: [{ price: 51 }, { price: 51 }] }, { code: "Y", pricings: [{ price: 88 }, { price: 88 }] }, { pricings: [{ price: 7 }, { price: 42 }, { price: 33 }] }],
    sums = array.map(({ pricings }) => pricings.reduce((s, { price }) => s + price, 0)),
    result = [...sums.keys()]
        .sort((a, b) => sums[b] - sums[a])
        .map(i => array[i]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I didn't know that you can use `{}` like this in the `map`-function :D
Thanks for this great solution @Nina Scholz.

Comment: it's a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Answer (score 4):

Your solution is good but you can skip the `.map()` and store the reducer function beforehand.

```
const sumPrice = (acc,val) => acc + val.price;
arr.sort((a, b) => b.pricings.reduce(sumPrice,0) - a.pricings.reduce(sumPrice,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to map it first, just sort on the reduction:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => {
  const sumA = a.pricings.reduce((sum, entry) => sum + entry.price, 0);
  const sumB = b.pricings.reduce((sum, entry) => sum + entry.price, 0);
  return sumA - sumB;
});
```

You might even consider pre-processing the array into a new one where each entry is an object with the pre-computed sum and a reference to the original, then map it; should increase performance by not making reduce calls multiple times during sorting:

```
const mapped = arr.map(entry => {
  const sumEntry = entry.pricings.reduce((sum, pricing) => sum + pricing.price, 0);
  return {
    entry,
    sum: sumEntry

  }
});
mapped.sort((a, b) => a.sum - b.sum).map(value => value.entry);
```